# Как сделать повторное срабатывание события

Tags: c#, winforms

пытаюсь сделать фитрацию данных в таблице, посредством нажатия на заголовок столбца.
Данные в этом столбце разные, хотел сделать так - что при на заголовок , отображались сначала одни данные , потом другие и тд.
Не могу додумать как это сделать! Проверка на нажалие просто обходит вторую часть цикла.
Подскажите пожалуйста.

```
private void dataGridView1_ColumnHeaderMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
    {

        
        if (dataGridView1.Columns[6].HeaderText == "Статус" & e.Clicks == 1)
        {

            var statusClick = context.Inventories.Select(x => new
            {
                id = x.Inventid,
                name = x.Inventname,
                serial = x.Serialnum,
                datepov = x.Datepov,
                datenextpov = x.Datenextpov,
                filial = x.Filial.Filialname,
                status = x.Status.Statusname,
                service = x.Service.Servicename,
                yearofman = x.Yearofman
            }).AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.status == "Поверено")
          .ToList();
            dataGridView1.DataSource = statusClick;

        }   
        else if (dataGridView1.Columns[6].HeaderText == "Статус" & e.Clicks == 2) 
         {
                var statusClick = context.Inventories.Select(x => new
                {
                    id = x.Inventid,
                    name = x.Inventname,
                    serial = x.Serialnum,
                    datepov = x.Datepov,
                    datenextpov = x.Datenextpov,
                    filial = x.Filial.Filialname,
                    status = x.Status.Statusname,
                    service = x.Service.Servicename,
                    yearofman = x.Yearofman
                }).AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.status == "Не поверяется")
        .ToList();
                dataGridView1.DataSource = statusClick;

                
        }
```

Comment: Есть событие `ColumnHeaderMouseDoubleClick` https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.columnheadermousedoubleclick Ну, либо я не понял вопроса.

Comment: @aepot  Да, я и обрабатываю это событие, дело в том, что он не переключается между if'ами, а выдает только первый результат

Comment: Уберите `AsEnumerable`. Вызов `Where` поставьте перед `Select`.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov поясните пожалуйста, зачем вызов Where ставить перед Select?

Comment: Сейчас у вас все данные из БД загружаются в память. И лишь после этого фильтруются. Если в таблице будут миллионы строк, то код работать будет медленно, памяти жрать много. / Фильтрацию нужно делать непосредственно в БД. Если переместить `Where`, то EF сгенерирует эффективный sql-код. Впрочем, если это действительно Entity Framework, а не что-то другое.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov я сам в EF не очень. Буду благодарен, если отредактируете ответ и доработаете запрос. Это может пригодиться будущим посетителям.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не повторяйте свой код. Используйте методы.

```
private void FilterStatus(string status)
{
    var filtered = context.Inventories.Select(x => new
    {
        id = x.Inventid,
        name = x.Inventname,
        serial = x.Serialnum,
        datepov = x.Datepov,
        datenextpov = x.Datenextpov,
        filial = x.Filial.Filialname,
        status = x.Status.Statusname,
        service = x.Service.Servicename,
        yearofman = x.Yearofman
    }).AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.status == status)
    .ToList();
    dataGridView1.DataSource = filtered;
}
```

Тогда можно написать вот такой обработчик.

```
private string currentStatus = "Поверено";

private void SwitchStatus()
{
    if (currentStatus == "Поверено")
        currentStatus = "Не поверяется";
    else
        currentStatus = "Поверено";
}

private void dataGridView1_ColumnHeaderMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (dataGridView1.Columns[6].HeaderText == "Статус")
    {
        SwitchStatus();
        FilterStatus(currentStatus);
    }
}
```

Вот и вся магия.

Но в целом, у вас идет запрос к БД на каждый такой клик. А стоит ли? Быть может проще не обращаться к БД, а изначально загрузить из нее все данные, а фильтровать их через [BindingSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.bindingsource)? Подумайте над этим.

---

Еще обратите внимание на `&` в условии, изучите разницу между `&` и `&&`.

Comment: А посдкажите пожалуйста, если статусов не 2, а больше , как тогда реализовать SwitchStatus?

Comment: @KuroIsekai перепишите метод `SwitchStatus` как вам нравится. Можно выбрать все уникальные статусы из БД запросом, и затем хранить индекс статуса в массиве статусов и покругу иего переключать.